# "put something off 3 days" vs "put off something for 3 days"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I have seen some sentences, like these, using prepositions before the time delayed.

> They put off the event for five days.

But is it okay to leave out 'for' in both the following cases?

> I put the appointment off three days.
>
> I put off the appointment three days.

The 'put something off x days' structure doesn't seem wrong to me, because 'off' seems like a preposition, here.

('Put off something' is right, but I know sometimes "put something off" is used, even though *something* is not pronoun, so I used both forms.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the appropriate preposition (for).

Depending on where you are, the other constructions may or may not be common or acceptable. They are not where I am from.

Comment: Please tell us where you're from. (I mean, at least specify if you are talking about the UK, the US, Australia, Canada, etc..)

Comment: You don't need the for. It is  optional.

Comment: @J.R. I'm from USA

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct: to put off something for three days and to put something off for three days. Both have the same meaning. Some phrasal verbs work both ways: with the preposition after the verb or with the preposition after a direct object.

**To put off something for three days** = 
**To put something off for three days**.
The two ways of saying this are semantically equivalent (mean the same thing).

Answer (score -1):

Certain prepositions must follow certain words, and the correct preposition must be used to make relationships between words in the sentences clear.

Able *to*
Capable *of*
Preoccupied *with*
Concerned *by*
Prohibited *from*

Prepositions must be followed by nouns, and prepositions can only go on the end of the sentence in certain situations.